# proper way of handling fatal errors in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

According to [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) usually, it's not a good idea to use `process.exit()` because async IO operations like `console.log()` or other logging methods ([Pino](https://getpino.io/) logging library in my case) might get skipped, the process exits before they complete their task. I was wondering what is the best way to handle errors inside a function. My final goal is to handle errors in a function and if the error is a fatal error then exit the process.

I wrote a simplified version of what I currently think is the best option (similar to the solution explained in Node.js docs):

```
const validateUserInput = (input) => {
  try {
    if (input === 'wrong') { throw new Error('sample error'); } // simplified
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('last message');
    // process.exit(1) --> using this might skip IO operation like the log on previous line
    process.exitCode = 1;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

if (validateUserInput('wrong')) {
  // rest of the code
}

// nothing should be written here
```

Comment: Just *don't* handle them with `try`/`catch`. Uncaught exceptions will exit (crash) the process by default, and IO that needs to complete (like logging libraries) will hook onto that to handle the crash gracefully.

Comment: https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors is a good guide

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that I want to create proper messages for each message. Other than that I can throw an arbitrary error to achieve what you are saying. Then another problem is that it will print the error content in console and I don't know how to avoid that. This can be a solution if there is a way to avoid printing uncaught exceptions messages on console, but Idk if it's the best solution or not!

Comment: You can of course `catch` errors and re`throw` a different one with a more appropriate message. But still, avoid `process.exit` :-)

Comment: "*it will print the error content in console and I don't know how to avoid that*" - you can use [`process.on('uncaughtException')`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception) for that. (Same for unhandled promise rejections). Your logging library might even do that for you, see its documentation (https://getpino.io/#/docs/help?id=exit-logging)

Answer (score 2):

> SIGTERM is the signal that tells a process to gracefully terminate. It
> is the signal that's sent from process managers like upstart or
> supervisord and many others.
>
> You can send this signal from inside the program, in another function: [read more](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program)

```
process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
```

You can also setup your own listeners for this event, and perform other tasks.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Shutting down the application ...')
  })
})
```

But `SIGTERM` is not supported on windows, so you can use `SIGINT` instead, here is a useful info about `SIGINT`

> After the SIGINT signal is received, the Node.js server initiates a
> shutdown sequence and enters shutdown mode. All of the existing
> requests are completed and no new requests are entertained. When the
> last request completes, the server closes all of the connections and
> shuts down. [read more](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/elm/6.0.6?topic=server-shutting-down-nodejs)

Mor about processes [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

Comment: Updated both quotes with their source links.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the code that comes right after `process.kill` still gets called. I have also tried `process.emit`.

Answer (score 0):

If a fatal error occurs, the application will need to be terminated gracefully to prevent default behavior from happening and allow additional statements to execute first.
You can achieve this by creating a simple event listener:

```
// For app termination
const gracefulShutdown = (msg, callback) => {
    server.close(() => {
        //execute additional code here
        console.log(`Application disconnected through ${msg}`);
        callback();
    })
}

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    //execute additional code here
    gracefulShutdown('app termination', () => {
        process.exitCode = 1;
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand how this is the answer to my question!

Comment: @Amir...I'm sorry this isn't helpful. I was going by "My final goal is to handle errors in a function and if the error is a fatal error then exit the process" in your question.
What were you looking for?

Comment: My problem is that I want to write proper logs (like not showing stack trace) before exit. If I call the `process.exit()` then the log might get missed, because it's async. If I don't call `process.exit()` then I need to handle the rest of the code, so nothing else gets executed. I don't think `SIGINT` help with anything here.

Comment: @server-unknown I think the OP already knows how to distinguish non-fatal from fatal errors. The question is explicitly only about fatal errors. You might want to drop the first half of your answer, everything before "*If a fatal error occurs, …*".